# How do I speed up this Mersenne Prime py in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I wish to optimize and speed up this py in Python 2.7, which finds Mersenne Primes and filters non-mersenne primes and filters even numbers. The number 2 does not work, but that's ok.  The code finds M44497 in 26 seconds.  On a faster CPU it finds it in 15 seconds.  It found M859433 in 7.5 hours.  How can I say make M44497 run in under 7 seconds just hoping you guys know.

```
import time
def myfunction():
myfunction()

def prime_sieve():                         
yield 2; yield 3; yield 5; yield 7;   

def mod_mersenne(n, prime, mersenne_prime):
while n > mersenne_prime:
n = (n & mersenne_prime) + (n >> prime)
if n== mersenne_prime:


return 0
return n
def is_mersenne_prime(prime, mersenne_prime): 
s = 4
for i in range(prime - 2):

s = mod_mersenne((s*s - 2), prime, mersenne_prime)
return s == 0

def calculate_perfects(n):

primes = prime_sieve()
next(primes)                     
if is_mersenne_prime(n,(2**n - 1) ):
yield((2**n-1 ))

print ("Mersenne Determinate Program Tom O'Neil, The Program only prints Mersenne 
Primes and it filters non-mersenne primes and even numbers.  The number 2 returns 
nothing!")
def runpro():

keep_running = True


num = int(input('Enter a number to test: '))



while keep_running:
    start = time.time()  
    for perfect in calculate_perfects(num):

    print ((True))
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print "\tfound in %.f seconds" % elapsed

    start = time.time()     
    num = int(input('Enter a number to test: '))


    if num == 0:
    keep_running = False

    runpro()
```

Comment: Using a language other than Python is your best bet for speed: it's going to handle those for and while loops slowly. Julia might be a good choice for an alternative interpreted language. You could also look into the Python numba JIT compiler, or Cython.

Comment: Hi, Richard and tips, for Cython for this script.  I believe I need a C++ compiler and pip install  cython.  Any help would be great. :)

Comment: I'm sure if you Google around, StackOverflow has a number of questions and answers related to getting Cython running.

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow the code you have posted (please indent properly), but it may be useful to cache/memoize calculation results. E.g. have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) and [here](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Questions about optimizing or refactoring code are better suited to [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you tried [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)?

Comment: Richard I managed to cythonize the py but I only shaved 1 second off M44497 to 25 seconds, oh well at least I learned something :)

Answer (score 0):

You can employ gmpy2, i created a program that does both and you can see that gmpy2 can solve it in just over 2 seconds:

```
def makersmarknongmpy2(n):
  z = 9
  mask = (1<<n)-1
  
  def mer_rem(x, bits): 
      # Below is same as:   return x % mask 
      while True: 
          r = 0
          while x != 0: 
              r += x & mask 
              x >>= bits 
          if r == mask: 
              r = 0 
          if r < mask: 
              return r 
          x = r 
              
  for x in range(n-1):
     z = mer_rem(z * z, n)
  return z == 9

import gmpy2

def makersmark(n):
  z = 9
  mask = gmpy2.mpz((1<<n)-1)
  
  def mer_rem(x, bits): 
      # Below is same as:   return x % mask 
      while True: 
          r = gmpy2.mpz(0) 
          while x != 0: 
              r += x & mask 
              x >>= bits 
          if r == mask: 
              r = gmpy2.mpz(0) 
          if r < mask: 
              return r 
          x = r 
        
  z = gmpy2.mpz(z)
  n = gmpy2.mpz(n)       
  for x in range(n-1):
     z = mer_rem(z * z, n)
  return z == 9
  
start = time.time()
print(makersmark(44497)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

True
2.0241031646728516


start = time.time()
print(makersmarknongmpy2(44497)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

True
16.902064561843872
```